# App/Homepage displaying as blank window while using class structures with tkinter in Python 3.7

Tags: python-3.x, class, user-interface, tkinter

I'm brand new to python/programming (2-3 weeks experience) and I'm trying to make a GUI app with tkinter for a Battleship game that I wrote originally as a cmd line game for my first project. I would like this GUI to have a few different screens/frames that walk the user through setting up and playing the game in single player or two player modes.

PROBLEM: I am able to procedurally generate a single homepage in a window with the background image that I want placed as a label, however when I try to implement that same code into a class structure to start making multiple screens, the script will run but all I get is a window that is completely blank.

Most of the class structure code is pulled more or less straight from a tutorial, and I've also seen it floating around the forum in this context. However, most of the questions I've found on it seem to deal with errors, whereas my code runs, it just doesn't do what I want. I'm still learning about OOP and class structures so I assume I'm missing something straightforward.

I have tried declaring the keys:values for the self.frames dictionary individually instead of using the for loop.

I have separately tried using .pack, .grid, and .place to place the container and homepage/twoplayer frames.

I have tried storing the image I want to place as a background in a class variable instead of an instance variable. (Another question on multiple frames with tkinter suggested that could potentially be an issue in some circumstances)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Battleship(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry("1920x1080")

        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Homepage, Twoplayer):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Homepage)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        """Show given frame"""
        frame=self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class Homepage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # Add battleship photo to background
        mainBG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("CSEdit.jpg"))
        BGlabel = Label(parent, image=mainBG)
        BGlabel.grid()


class Twoplayer(Frame):
    # This code not relevant to problem, can't even get Homepage to work

root = Battleship()
root.mainloop()
```

When I don't use a class structure, this works to create the screen I want for the homepage in a window:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root=Tk()
root.geometry("1920x1080")
container=Frame(root)
container.pack(side="top", fill= "both")

mainBG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("CSEdit.jpg"))
BGlabel = Label(container, image=mainBG)
BGlabel.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

However, trying to create that screen similarly but within the class structure only produces a blank white window.

Comment: there is bug which removes `PhotoImage` from memory when it is created in function and assigned to local variable. You have to assign `PhotoImage` to class variable - `self.mainBG`. See "Note" on page: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: as for me you should use `self`, instead of `parent` in `Label(self, ...)` - with `self` you put `Label` in `Homepage(Frame)`. With `parent` you put Label in `container` and it may be invisible - ie. hidden under `Homepage(Frame)`. In old version you had only `containter` and `Label` (`container<-Label`) in class you have `container<-Homepage<-Label` so label need different parent - `Homepage` instead of `container`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one mistake and one problem with bug.

1. You put `Label` in `parent` which means `container` but you have to put it in `Homepage` - it means `self`.

   ```
   BGlabel = Label(self, image=self.mainBG)
   ```
2. there is bug which removes `PhotoImage` from memory when you create it in function and assign to local variable. You have to assign to global or class variable - ie. `self.main.BG`

   ```
   self.mainBG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("CSEdit.jpg"))
   BGlabel = Label(self, image=self.mainBG)
   ```

Working code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class Battleship(Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.geometry("1920x1080")

        container = Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both")
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Homepage, Twoplayer):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky = "nsew")

        self.show_frame(Homepage)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        """Show given frame"""
        frame=self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()


class Homepage(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # Add battleship photo to background
        self.mainBG = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("CSEdit.jpg"))
        BGlabel = Label(self, image=self.mainBG)
        BGlabel.grid()


class Twoplayer(Frame):
    # This code not relevant to problem, can't even get Homepage to work
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        pass

root = Battleship()
root.mainloop()
```